# chrome extension jquery search ajaxify error

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<li class="_penn __MenuItem" role="presentation">
<a class="_venn" href="#" rel="async-post" ajaxify="/ajax/address.com?id=tom" 
   role="menuitem"><span><span class="_5bib">Mark it up</span></span></a>
```

there is many `<a class="_venn"` on page, so i decide to search base on "ajaxify"

1. I need to do it all on JQuery. (suppose to make thing more easy..)
2. I want to click on this code:

   ```
   <a class="_venn" href="#" rel="async-post" ajaxify="/ajax/address.com?id=tom" 
      role="menuitem"><span><span class="_5bib">Mark it up< /span>< /span></a>
   ```
3. Using JQUERY `ajaxify~="ajax/address.com"` ?

   ```
   $("li a[ajaxify~='ajax/address.com']").each(function(){  
     // not work: [ajaxify~='ajax/address.com']  .. 
     // works, but many aquired: $("li a").each(function(){ 

     $(this).click();     // also not works..

     console.log($(this));

   });
   ```

what should i do..? is it a bug?

Comment: thanks.. im new, i can not edit it..  :p
.
<li class="_penn __MenuItem" role="presentation">
<a class="_venn" href="#" rel="async-post" ajaxify="/ajax/address.com?id=tom" 
   role="menuitem"><span><span class="_5bib">Mark it up</span></span></a>

</li>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure, but i think the solve are:

For all ajaxify:

```
$.each($('a[ajaxify]'), function(i,v){
  $(this).click();
}
```

Foe exactly one:

```
$('a[ajaxify="/ajax/address.com?id=tom"]').click();
```

If it is not - please give me more details.

Comment: thanks for your kind. :) 
using [ajaxify] works ! $("li a[ajaxify]").each(function(){  
.
 $(this).click(); // this one not working yet..

$('a[ajaxify="/ajax/address.com?id=tom"]')  // Yes, this one works too.